# Detect OS, Browser, Adobe Reader, Bandwidth, etc

Tags: php, browser, operating-system, detect

Basically, I am trying to create a compatibility test for some online programs, and I would like the user to see if they are compatible with the system I have in place sort of like it is found [here](http://www.identifix.com/compatibility.asp).

I am using WordPress for the site but could not find a plugin, PHP or Javascript source that will allow all these things to be detected. The website may be using ASP, but I figured this should be detectable through PHP as well, correct?

Comment: The question is too broad. It's like eight questions into one: Browser Version, Computer Platform, Adobe Reader, Adobe Flash Player, Cookies Support, Scripting Support, Connection Speed, Current Date/Time.  [BrowserHawk](http://www.cyscape.com/showbrow.aspx?bhcp=1) is a tool that does a lot in terms of testing capabilities

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I looked into Browserhawk, but it is quite expensive for a cloud service, but nice to know that it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS can be detected with the User-Agent by looking into `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. The browser is also into the User-Agent. The Adobe Reader cannot be readed with php but with JavaScript in the `navigator.plugins` object. The bandwith is not simple to detect.

About the User Agent my currient one is this here:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0

That means I use Firefox in version 19.0 on a Windows 7 x64.

For detecting the actual Adobe Reader version loop thrue the plugins and look for the name (property) ***Adobe Acrobat*** in my case `navigator.plugins[2].version` returns ***10.1.6.1***.

About the bandwidth you could try to download data and measure how long that takes. But note that there are cases where you will waste the traffic of the user especially on mobile devices. However you should avoid that in most cases the actual bandwidth is not important.

Answer (score 0):

http://thecodeabode.blogspot.ca/2011/01/detect-adobe-reader-plugin.html

Same as the above answer mostly, Using navigator.plugins you can detect things like Adobe Reader. However to detect bandwidth you'd need to create a timed script to log how long it takes them to retrieve a file. For instance http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
You could load an image via javascript, or make an image file outputted by PHP.

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Last-Modified: $ts");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
?>
```

This would time how long it takes for the server/client to load the outputted image.
After $total_time you can put into a database such as mysql how long it took for them to load a 6MB image. You then divide the SIZE by the TIME. So if it took 2 seconds they would have say a 3Mbps connection. 
Adding on:

```
8 Bits = 1 Byte
1024 Bytes = 1 KiloByte
1024 KiloBytes = 1 MegaByte
1024 MegaBytes = 1 GigaByte
1024 GigaBytes = 1 TeraByte
```

So if say a user loads 1MB in 1 second, try 2MB, and so on.
But if it takes longer. Say 14 seconds to download 1MB Divide 1/14

```
0.125MB = 1 megabit
6/0.125/1 = 48 Mbit(Mbps)
1/0.125/14 = 0.57Mbit
```